# Camry window problem

Tags: toyota, camry, power-windows, weather-dependent

I have a Toyota Camry 2010. Each year it gets worse. The driver’s window always rolls down and up. But if it has been sitting there and it is hot the other three windows won’t roll down from the driver’s seat. Then I have to roll down the windows individually. Once the car gets moving the windows roll down and up from the driver’s seat. If gets really hot the windows may not roll up. Again I can individually do this. Each year it takes less heat for this problem to occur. This was the first year a window wouldn’t roll up from the driver’s side.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Isn’t that going to make the windows dirty and greasy?

Comment: Did you mean to put that comment under the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I would start by spraying all of the rubber guides that the window runs in with a silicone spray.  Spray plenty on so that it runs down the guides that go inside the door.  Wind the window up and down a few times so that it spreads out.  If you apply this every now and then your windows should move a lot faster.

For [example](https://www.amazon.co.uk/151-Silicone-Lubricating-Spray-200ml/dp/B07571WSH6/ref=sr_1_7?keywords=silicone%20spray&qid=1686299253&sr=8-7) -

[image]